# How to implment a GCM Server in C# that supports CCS

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I'm trying to write a 3rd party server application for sending and receiving notifications from Android devices using GCM's CCS as outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html). I'm leveraging PushSharp for handling the sending of notifications from my server app, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to receive messages at the server level. Is this supported or is there another 3rd party XMPP library for .NET that handles this cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can receive messages at server level, this is not the point in push notifications. if you want to send information to the service from the app, i would suggest writing a webservice. i've implemented this myself, and had to do a little digging to find some code that could communicate with the webservice as it was written in c# and the app was java, but i can paste some code that might help if you think that would help you communicate.

Long story short though, if you want an app to talk to a server, then write a web service. if you want a server to talk to an app, use push notifications.